# Silverlight 4 Render to WriteableBitmap returns empty bitmap

Tags: c#, silverlight, writeablebitmap

I have some code that aims to render a ControlTemplate to a writeableBitmap. The code to create the WBMP is as follows:

```
    private static void OnMarkerPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var template = e.NewValue as ControlTemplate;
        if (template != null)
        {
            var c = new Marker();
            c.Template = template;
            c.ApplyTemplate();
            c.MeasureArrange();
            c.Width = c.DesiredSize.Width;
            c.Height = c.DesiredSize.Height;

            // _cachedBitmap is of type WriteableBitmap
            _cachedBitmap = c.RenderToBitmap();
        }
    }
```

Where the following extension methods are defined:

```
    internal static void MeasureArrange(this UIElement element)
    {
        element.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        element.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), element.DesiredSize));
    }

    public static WriteableBitmap RenderToBitmap(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        int width = (int)element.DesiredSize.Width;
        int height = (int)element.DesiredSize.Height;

#if SILVERLIGHT
        var result = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
        result.Render(element, new TranslateTransform());
        result.Invalidate();
        return result;
#else
        // WPF Impl works just fine
        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        bmp.Render(element);
        return new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
#endif         
    }
```

and Marker is defined as an empty control

```
public class Marker : Control
{         
}
```

The issue is this. In WPF this all works fine, as it does in Silverlight after the first attempt to create the bitmap. However, the first attempt fails, returning a WriteableBitmap of the correct size (7*7, or 49 pixels) but with all zeros in the `int[] Pixels` array.

Some things which may be of helpful. Immediately before WriteableBitmap creation in `RenderToBitmap`, the width/height of the element is 7,7, the Desired Size is (7,7) but the ActualWidth/ActualHeight is (0,0). In WPF I believe all are (7,7). So this may be a layout issue not a

FYI the Marker and ControlTemplate never make it to the visual tree. This is a purely cached bitmap implementation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found an answer. Although I don't know why. "Answer" ticks goes to anyone who can explain it.

I found [this link](http://khason.net/blog/quick-silverlight-tip-why-my-actualwidth-and-actualheight-equal-0/) which suggests ActualWidth / ActualHeight are evaluated asynchronously hence a well-place BeginInvoke can solve the problem. Why does this work in WPF but not silverlight?

```
        var c = new PointMarker();
        c.Template = pointMarkerTemplate;
        c.ApplyTemplate();

        // DispatcherUtil is just a proxy around Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
        DispatcherUtil.Instance.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            c.MeasureArrange();
            c.Width = c.DesiredSize.Width;
            c.Height = c.DesiredSize.Height;
            series._pointMarkerCache = c.RenderToBitmap();
            series.OnInvalidateParentSurface();
        });
```

Comment: Probably the Silverlight Measurement pass that calculates ActualWidth/ActualHeight is 1st resetting those to 0 before recalculating new values and setting them before returning. So I guess that if your code executes at other thread than that code, you might read the values during the recalculation and thus read 0. However this would be a case if some resize event was causing the recalculation to occur, don't see why it would recalculate those values all the time